# how to check if two images are same using c

Tags: c, image, comparison, libjpeg

i have a embedded device. in this it produces some output images from a remote source which are screenshots from a live stream in an interval of every 1 second. i need to compare 1st picture with next 10 pictures every 10 minutes to detect if stream is frozen.

this device has c and c++ access and very limited memory, what i will be getting is jpeg images. i can decompress jpeg images with `libjpeg`
i am affried to use corner detection and sift because it will result in false positive if image rotated. also i can't opencv

when i compare with `memcmp()` after decompressing  i am getting they are different. i tried to convert to greyscale using

`cinfo.out_color_space =  JCS_GRAYSCALE;`

how can i compare 1 image at a time with 1st image. i only need comparison part, managing memory is implemented.

#### UPDATE

i cant compare the raw images because it will include some timstamps attached,
if the image is 517 pixels in height, i need to compare only first 400 columns
so my code is

```
 // The row_stride is the total number of bytes it takes to store an
 // entire scanline (row).
 row_stride = width * pixel_size;
 while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.output_height)
        {
            unsigned char *buffer_array[1];
            buffer_array[0] = bmp_buffer + \
                       (cinfo.output_scanline) * row_stride;

            jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, buffer_array, 1);
        }
        jpeg_finish_decompress(&cinfo);
        jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);

        checking_buff = (unsigned char *)malloc((size_t)(row_stride*400));
```

then do `memcmp()` comparison with first sample

Comment: Why would the image become rotated if the stream is "frozen"? And if it's a user-setting that might be changed during those ten minutes you check, then just wait until the next ten-minute span.

Comment: What if it's not frozen, but whatever the camera is pointed at just didn't change at all?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Considering that the images a compressed using a lossy algorithm, minute changes in light might create big bitwise changes in the images.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But then `memcmp()` on the compressed images (wouldn't even need to decompress them) would be sufficient, yet the question strongly implies that it's not.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Correct, `memcmp` (even on the compressed data) *should* have worked. So either the stream isn't "frozen" or there is some other (unknown to us) problem.

Comment: @AndrewHenle @Someprogrammerdude hi i updated my question to show why ``memcmp()`` on raw didn't worked

Comment: If the timestamps on the images keep changing, is the stream actually frozen, then? Wouldn't a new timestamp mean the images are fresh? Unless you have some component in the system that keeps reusing the previous image, but still refreshes the timestamp... (that sounds odd to me)

Comment: @ilkkachu it is a problem with image production program in remote system, i can't control it

Comment: Perhaps you could start by using a binary comparison tool such as BeyondCompare, etc. to look at the raw data to see how similar it actually is.  As stated, if the data is the same, memcmp() should work.  Maybe there is some other embedded data that needs to be stripped.